# Microplanting my own coffee

Tags: growing, farming

I live in Czech Republic. Quite far away from coffee belt.

If I wanted to plant, harvest, process and roast my own coffee, would I be able to actually do it?

- I have my own garden
- Obtaining coffe plant to actually plant it would be a challenge, but not impossible
- I could plant it in my own greenhouse.
- Obviously, I do not plan to sell it for business, just for my own purposes.

So, theoretically: Am I able to actually produce me coffee in "drinkable" quality?

Comment: see this question for how much a single tree grows: http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-many-plants-are-needed-to-brew-a-coffee
and see this question: http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/56/how-to-grow-coffee-at-home/64#64
for growing tips at home. A garden will be different and your climate will have it's own differences but those might help.

Comment: The first one is mine ;) Part of microplanting plan :D

Comment: So then you just need to find the specific coffee plant that will handle your climate the best. What altitude do you live at?

Comment: roughly 840 feets above the sea level (254 metres)

Comment: That is gonna be a problem for you. Coffee will grow at low altitudes if the temperature and water is sufficient, but it will grow slow and the flavor of your beans will suffer greatly. Best conditions are above 3,000 ft. Check out the info here: http://www.scribblerscoffee.com/flavor_effect_of_altitude

Comment: This question ("would I be able to actually do it?") seems either a bit broad, or a bit "yes or no" to me. Maybe a bit more focus would help? Eg. are you trying to figure out if the climate or soil in your region will be condusive to coffee growing? Are you trying to figure out if it's legally possible to import coffee plants into your country? Etc.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you can if you can first make a decent coffee plant(s) to first make the coffee. Using this [website](http://www.thanksgivingcoffee.com/blog/?p=174) can help you with your gardening/farming of coffee plants. It is mainly based in the USA so sorry! Some tips to notice for decent coffee beans:

- Don't put coffee plants in direct sunlight for too long. It will kill your plant and ruin your life. Most coffee plants need little sunlight to survive.
- It takes 10 minutes of frost/3 hours of direct sunlight outside from May and November will kill it.
- Place it near or at the east-facing window to get a good morning sun and just enough sunlight from the afternoon.
- Use warm water but don't flood the pots with it.

Making the drinkable coffee will the hard part I guess. Here is a seemingly a good website for roasting at home: [Roasting at Home](http://www.breworganic.com/coffee/howtoroast.htm). Remember to use green, unroasted coffee beans!

Comment: Any news on my answer? <br> I hope it is ***helpful***